# Write the parabolic equation in the form $y=a(x-h)^2+k$ with the following information

Tags: conic-sections

It's been a while since I've done this, and I've forgotten the first steps. Any hints/pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Write the equation for the parabola in the form $y=a(x-h)^2+k$ with the following information: Congruent to $y=\frac{1}{2}x^2$; minimum value of $-5$, equation of axis of symmetry $x=-8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$y = a (x-h)^2 +k \ge k$ when $a>0$.

The axis of symmetry is $x = h$.

Comment: So 1/2 is the a value, -5 is the k value and -8 would be the h value, which would make the answer be y=1/2(x+8)^2-5?

Comment: @Grimestock Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you for your help!